# Paleomix command won't work - python version in bash needs to be 2.7

Tags: bash, python

I want to use the Paleomix toolset and while I have installed everything with pip into a new conda environment, but I needed to install pip first, which led to a version change in Python from 2 to 3. Paleomix requires version 2, so I am assuming this is one of the reasons the command won't work.
How do I change the Python version in my environment? I have tried aliases but they don't work.

Comment: Which Ubuntu are you on?  It may be as simple as installing the python 2 packages.  `pip` won't upgrade you from Py2 to Py3.

Comment: I'm using the Terminal in my Mac, accessing the server at my school through a bash shell (version 4.3.48(1))

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Is the server at school Ubuntu, or no?  If it isn't then this is offtopic here on Ask Ubuntu.  If it is, then you should probably NOT be trying to `pip` install things.  You should be talking to the school IT staff who manage the server, since `pip` being Python3 means that Python 2 is not installed and needs to be manually installed from the package repositories.

Comment: They said it was ubuntu when we started the class, but did not say what version it was.  This is what I did to solve the problem:
I installed python 2 into my environment with conda:
conda create --name paleo python=2.7
And after that I used pip to install paleomix and got it to run.

pip install --user paleomix

I made sure to do this first:

echo "export PATH=\$PATH:~/.local/bin" >> ~/.bash_profile

after adding export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin to my .bash_profile.

Now the paleomix command works

Comment: You might want to add that as an answer so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

`export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin`

to your .bash_profile. To find your .bash_profile, open it in a text editor such as nano:

```
nano .bash_profile
```

There you can paste the command. Or you make sure it is there by doing this:

```
echo "export PATH=\$PATH:~/.local/bin" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

In order to solve the problem with Paleomix: I installed python 2 into my environment (named paleo) with conda:

```
conda create --name paleo python=2.7
```

Make sure you have pip installed in your environment.

```
conda install -c anaconda pip
```

And after that I used pip to install paleomix and got it to run.

`pip install --user paleomix`

Now the paleomix command works.